# AC current direction

Tags: power, ac

Calculating The  complex power of the 120 supply.
$$ S = V_{rms} \times I_{rms}^* $$
should I consider I negative since it's entering the negative terrminal?
I am really confused here!
so assuming $$i^* = 10 j \ \    S_{120} = - V \times i^* = - 120 (-j) \times 10 j = -1200 VA \angle 0 $$
[image: circut]

Comment: Bigger problem here is you do not understand passive sign convention. Get that cleared up first. It's far more important than the immediate question you are asking.

Comment: I have the S of 150 source, I calculated the i from it. the same i will be used in the 120 source?